# Facebook api, feed vs post and the weird results (and maybe some other feedback)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

after studying pretty long on the FB api i finally understand the context these 'apps' work in and get access tokens etc. etc.

There is however, something that's bothering me. I'm pretty sure someone already asked, but i can't find the right search words, and im sorry in advance!

Ok here goes:

I'm building a webpage onto which i would like to show my last 10 facebook posts. The authentication flow i'm using is:

1. login to my site (Django app),
2. use the javascript api to log in to FB and get an access token,
3. send this access_token to the server via and xhr request,
4. have the server send a request to FB, changing the access_token into
   a long-lived token and storing that token in the database so i can
   use that long lived token for later requests.

---

- QUESTION 1: Is this the right way to go?
- QUESTION 2: I read and    confirmed that my long-lived tokens are
  valid for 60 days. The docs    say this token is refreshed
  automatically, how does this work, do i    just have a log in again?

---

With the token (currently i just use access_token - short one - ) i query '/me/feed' or '/me/posts/' (all i want are status updates, photo's, shared links)
I understand the '/me/feed' > '/me/posts', because essentially, '/me/posts' are a subset of '/me/feed'.

---

- QUESTION 3: Am i correct assuming posts are a subset of feed?

---

The results i am getting from these queries seem 'a bit off', as the feed edge gives me the 3 latest objects, whereas the posts edge gives me 16 post objects. I am playing with the 'limit' parameter, but that just responds 'erratically'. I found out the default limit is 500.

---

- <strike>QUESTION 4: Why do i get more results from the posts edge than from
  the feed edge?</strike>
- <strike>QUESTION 5: Why don't i get 500 results as per default?</strike>
- <strike>QUESTION 6: How come using limit=10 does not work properly?</strike>

---

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction and help me with my questions.

Thanks in advance,
Niels

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I think you have far too many questions in your "question" for someone to give a reasonable answer and for it to be useful to others later.  Can you divide these into separate questions?

Comment: my answer here may help with the limits parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888441/facebook-graph-search-only-about-500-results-returned-regardless-of-limit-pass/9008767#9008767

Comment: Hi Tim, i think you are right. At question 6 i though 'not another..!'. You awnser in the other post is certainly helpful. Any idea why i get only 3 feed updates? I can't imagine loading a 4th or 5th would take much longer (referring to the 'good enough' principle)?

Comment: If you're looking for accuracy with Facebook you'll be frustrated every time.  It could be that the particular machine that responded to the query only had access to those 3, or the different queries work differently in the background (despite you expecting it to give the same result).  There's a very good chance that if you try it again in a week you'll get something completely different.